# Azure TLS Certificate changes clarification

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-active-directory, tls1.2, azure-appservice

I recently got an email from Microsoft regarding the TLS Certificate changes. Had some difficulty understanding few action steps regarding it. Can anyone please explain the below points in detail.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Would be a massive help!

Comment: Hello @SDS, The above pointers are to find if your application might be impacted by the upcoming certificate changes. Applications using certificate pinning need to check the thumbprint, Common Name, and other cert properties of any of the Microsoft IT TLS CAs match with https://www.microsoft.com/pki/mscorp/cps/default.htm

Comment: Please feel free to let us know if you need any further clarification.

Comment: Hey @Nishant-MSFTIdentity thanks so much for your reply!
Yes, could you please elaborate more on the CRL & OCSP action step. I'm not able to comprehend this one particularly. 
Thanks!

Comment: Hello @SD4, Thank You for the response. I have added an answer below. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TLS Change would apply to anyone who is trying to communicate to Azure services with their application. This is for applications/services etc. which call any Azure endpoint for execution. While calling the Azure endpoint the clients are required to present the certificate and trust the ones provided by Azure during the secure communications (a step called SSL handshake) between both the parties. In this case, the application needs to trust the Certificate authorities which granted the Azure service/endpoints the certificates so the certificate-based errors do not come during any secure communication between the application and Azure endpoints. Your application may be impacted if it explicitly specifies a list of acceptable CAs. This practice is known as certificate pinning.

There are some ways to detect if your application is impacted. You can follow the below article to find out more information:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/fundamentals/tls-certificate-changes#will-this-change-affect-me
- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/site-recovery-tls-certificate-update/

If you have any specific question, you can post the same in the below thread which is being continuously monitored for Azure TLS certificate questions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/117444/reminder-azure-tls-certificate-changes.html

Comment: Thanks for this Nishant!